# Function that has if statement produces nothing when it's called

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
#4 gender differences
def d_gender(employee1, employee2):
    if employee1.gender >= employee2.gender :
        1
    else :
        0

d_gender(E1,E2)
```

Although everything is defined the function doesn't produce anything. What is wrong here?

Comment: Why did you think it *would* produce something? What did you expect an integer on its own to do? And why would you return `0` and `1` anyway, rather than the boolean result of the comparison?

Comment: The function contains no `return` or `print` statements.  What did you expect it to _do_?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` statement in your function:

```
def d_gender(teacher, studio):
    if teacher.gender >= studio.gender :
        return 1
    else :
        return 0
```

Then you can decide what to do with the *returned value*. Maybe `print`:

```
print(d_gender(T1,S1))
```

Comment: H Moses, is it good to test functions like this though, by adding the function after its definition

Comment: I don't understand